# I have a firm job offer for a position but have been offered an interview for a better position

Tags: interviewing, job-acceptance

I went for an interview yesterday for a Lab Technician in a school. I was the only candidate for the job and I was offered it on the spot.  I said something like "Yes, but I need to discuss it with my wife first to confirm for certain"
The same day I received a call about another job for a position in Research and Development for well over double the salary.

The Lab Technician Job doesn't start until September and I haven't completely accepted although I did give a very very strong indication that I would. Is it ethical for me to attend an interview for the second job?  This only happened yesterday so could I phone the school and say I need more time to decide?  If so do I tell them about the second job?

Any advice would be extremely welcome as I don't want to be seen as unprofessional but the extreme difference in salary would mean a completely different life for my family and me.

Comment: Just as a company can interview multiple candidates for a position, you can interview with multiple companies. Nothing unethical or unprofessional about it.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't actually accepted the technician position.  Go to the other interview.  If you like it and they offer you a good deal, then accept it.

Think of the reverse.  What if the first place had said, *"We really like you, and want to offer you this job, but the dean has to approve it first"*.  Would there be anything wrong with them not eventually making you a real offer?  Of course not.

Since you gave the first place a vague indication you would accept the offer, it would be polite to inform them you won't be accepting as soon as you have received and accepted another job offer.

If they ask why, there is nothing wrong with telling them you found a job for more than double the pay.  Keep it factual.  Don't make it sound like *screw you*.  They are probably aware they were trying to pay a technician at well below market rate.  People bailing when they find a better opportunity is one of the consequences of that.  Keep in mind though, you didn't actually bail in this case since you never accepted the job.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it ethical for me to attend an interview for the second job?

Yes.

Since you haven't accepted another offer yet, you can and should continue to interview for other jobs.

> This only happened yesterday so could I phone the school and say I
>   need more time to decide?

That depends on how long you think it will take for you to make a decision regarding the second potential job.

If it will be within the next day or so, you could just wait without notifying the first company.

If you think it will take more than a day or two, you should call and ask for a few more days to decide.

Be ready with an answer (Yes or No) in case the first company needs a decision soon.

> If so do I tell them about the second job?

You could.

I wouldn't unless I needed more time than the first company seemed willing to grant and unless I was willing to forgo the first company offer in hopes of getting a job with the second company.

Either way, try to make a decision as quickly as you can, and inform the first company as soon as possible.